# Can I restore backup made using Ubuntu to a new operating system?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I have backed up some contents of my home directory to a USB hard drive using Ubuntu's built-in backup program.

Is it possible to perform a clean installation of Ubuntu, then restore the contents of my home directory using the backup copies stored on the USB drive? Is it possible to perform a clean installation of another operating system in which DejaDup can be installed (for example, Debian), then restore the contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The contents of a user's `~` do not affect the operating system itself, **however** the individual applications may be sensitive to changes in the formats and contents of configuration and data files stored within the home directory.

Comment: I think the username does have to be the same, though.

Comment: @Flimm: Not necessarily. That falls under the caveat in my answer.